# angularjs: updating $rootScope variables from a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

what is the angular way of updating a rootScope variable from a directive?
im having trouble understanding how scopes work in directives...

so far i can only change the variable on the scope level.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.foo = false;
}

app.directive('myDirective', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$parent.foo = true;
                scope.$parent.apply();
            });
        }
    }   
}]);

<!-- does not update foo -->
<p>{{ foo }}</p>

<!-- updates foo -->
<div my-directive><p>{{ foo }}</p></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to access `$rootScope` anywhere you need to inject it and it will become available:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {
                $rootScope.foo = true;
                $rootScope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }   
}]);
```

There is also simpler another approach that doesn't require injection. Every `scope` object has access to the topmost $rootScope via `$root` reference. It means that you could also do this:

```
scope.$root.foo = true;
```

Comment: thanks. so obvious. i also had to include $rootScope.$apply(); after setting the variable to update it.

Comment: @vesperae Hi, when I called $rootScope.$apply(), there is an error thrown: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog?p0=$apply

Comment: @PhuNguyen, that means angularjs is doing the $digest for you